# How to add a new directory in Magento 2.4.3 backend

Tags: magento2.4

How to add a new directory in Store-> Settings -> Configuration. I want to add a new directory with a php file Programatically

Answer (score 0):

The better way to add new section in `Store -> Settings -> Configuration` is to create `system.xml` file in a new module.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/config-reference-systemxml.html